# Will Macbook Air 2017 benefit from Catalina upgrade?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

I'm running Mojave on my Macbook Air (2017) and was wondering if anyone can recommend (or not) upgrading to Catalina now that 10.15.7 seems to be stable release.

I'm not using any 32bit apps, so no problems there.

However, is it worth actually upgrading? I know I can't use certain features (such as the battery health or sidecar), but should I do it for security, etc?

What are the experiences of other MBA 2017 owners after upgrade? Has anyone experienced slowdowns? Is anything actually better? Or should I just stick with Good Ol' Mojave?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, is it worth actually upgrading?

A newer macOS release always includes the latest security patches for any discovered hardware of software vulnerabilities. So generally speaking, it's a good idea to upgrade if your device supports running it, given you have no reason to refrain from upgrading.

> I know I can't use certain features (such as the battery health or sidecar), but should I do it for security, etc?

Yes.

> What are the experiences of other MBA 2017 owners after upgrade? Has anyone experienced slowdowns? Is anything actually better? Or should I just stick with Good Ol' Mojave?

This experience could be pretty subjective depending on the apps being used, but generally speaking, a newer release of macOS also often includes under the hood performance improvements which are also claimed about by Apple.

Comment: "pretty subjective" indeed! ;-) I held off on a Catalina upgrade for 9 months (2015 MacBook Pro) and it is still less stable than Mojave. If I had it to do over again I'd wait for the11.2 revision of Big Sur.

Comment: Apple releases security updates for more than just the latest OS version, so the security argument is not that strong. Example: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211849

Comment: @barbecue I'd agree with your argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well - I took the plunge and updated my MBA 2017 to Catalina and so far all seems well. Everything seems to be working OK, and I have (so far) not run in to any issues.

I did not have any 32 bit apps to worry about and I am pleased to see that my old M-Audio FastTrack guitar interface still works with Catalina, so all's good!

Fingers crossed I have not spoken too soon - I don't fancy the downgrade process (although it is allegedly no too difficult since I have a Time Machine backup from right before the upgrade).